# CListCtrl search by typing: how to show what's been typed?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, mfc, clistctrl

I have a `CListCtrl` in Report view, and I noticed that I can search by typing the first few letters of an item (the control selects the first item that matches as I type), and that this search "resets" after a second or so (so if I've typed "abc", pause, then type "d", then it searches for "d" only).  For usability, I want the user to realize that this search-by-typing feature exists.

So here are the options I can think of, in order of preference, and the question I have in each case:

1. Use whatever existing built-in support there is in MFC.

   - Is there such a thing?
2. Some other solution that's been implemented before.

   - Again, is there such a thing?
3. Add another textbox to the dialog box, and handle its `ON_EN_CHANGE` message to somehow trigger CListCtrl's search behavior.  In other words, similar to the find dialog/toolbar in browsers.

   - How do I trigger the search behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Did take a look into the List-View controls documentation on Microsoft Docs.
This behavior is described in the [Default List-View Message Processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/listview-message-processing) (`WM_CHAR` message). The search-string is indeed reset after one second.

However, I didn't find any notification message that seems to be relative, eg returning the current search-string, which you can display. There is the 
[LVN_INCREMENTALSEARCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvn-incrementalsearch), but the documentation is rather confusing (eg what is an "incremental search"? etc), and I don't know if you are going to receive this at all, as this seems to be about Virtual List-View controls. Anyway, you can give it a try.

But resetting the test entered by the user in just 1 sec may rather be unwelcome to users or reviewers (actually I have never seen an application doing so). So you can implement some "Search" operation in your dialog, as you said add an edit box and search for its content. You can use the [LVM_FINDITEM message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-finditem) (or the `ListView_FindItem()` macro) requesting a partial-match search (`LVFI_PARTIAL`), or do the search yourself (find the matching item and move there).

Comment: Thanks for finding these details - I don't know why I haven't noticed these in the docs.  I experimented with LVN_INCREMENTALSEARCH a little, and it only fires when a keypress triggers incremental search - not when the 1-second timeout clears the search string.  Seems to me Microsoft hadn't really intended for this search capability to be too customized; perhaps I do need to implement my own search.

Comment: FYI: incremental search seems to be a common term for this style of search function:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_search